# Ruby on Rails: проблема с active_admin и formtastic: undefined method 'item_item_colors_path' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, erb

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться в связке active_admin - formtastic
есть контроллер:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Item do

  controller do
    def new
      @item = Item.new
      @color = @item.ItemColors.build
    end
  end
```

и партиал:

```
<%= semantic_nested_form_for [@item, @color] do |f| %>
  <p>Category </p><%= f.input :category %></br>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :photo1 %>
  <%= f.fields_for :ItemColors do |i| %>
    <%= i.select :DetailColor_id, collection => DetailColor.all %>
    <%= i.text_field :size %>
    <%= i.link_to_remove "remove" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "add", :ItemColors %>
<% end %>
```

при попытке создать Item получаю:

> `undefined method 'item_item_colors_path' for
> <#<Class:0x00000003de0348>:0x00000003de2f30>`

Shrek: ок, буду знать

1101_debian: ItemColors - модель

модель Item:

```
has_many :DetailColors, :through => :ItemColors 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ItemColors, :allow_destroy => true accepts_nested_attributes_for :DetailColors
```

модель ItemColor:

```
belongs_to :Item
```

модель DetailColor:

```
has_many :Items, :through => :ItemColor
```

Comment: @Metallicolis название вопроса нужно писать понятнее, а не "Ruby on Rails", это копипаст и вопрос становится непонятен, что внутри ожидает.

Comment: а что такое ItemColors? Почему с большой буквы?

Comment: ItemColors промежуточная модель между Item и DetailColor

Answer (score 1):

Rails ожидает что вы будете придерживаться определённых правил именования. Переименуйте поля как принято, и очень может быть что ошибка исчезнет сама собой. Имена атрибутов в `lower_case`

Кроме того, покажите `rake routes` чтобы было понятней что у вас там. Покажите html-код который генерит `semantic_nested_form_for`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В общем эту проблему я уже решил переписав первую строчку в партиале: <%= semantic_nested_form_for @item, :url => admin_items_path do |f| %>. Все добавляется как надо. Но теперь другая проблема - не могу понять как вывести на индекс страницу значения из связанных форм, а именно ItemColor и size
Пробую так:
    column :item do |itemcolor|
      itemcolor
    end
получаю поле item с значениями типа: #<Category:0x000000081afa60>